# Ruby error: cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I've been having some major issues with Jekyll on windows. I finally get it working so i run

> jekyll build

Then

> jekyll serve --watch

Then i get the following error, can anyone help?

The full error is:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:207:in `load_dependent_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:33:in `load_dependent_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:198:in `usable?'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:25:in `usable?'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:57:in `block in select_and_initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:55:in `select_and_initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:291:in `initialize_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:283:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:52:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.0/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:56:in `watch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.0/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:8:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.0/bin/jekyll:97:in `
block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:155:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:66:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/d
elegates.rb:11:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/i
mport.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be running on a very old version of the `listen` gem (1.3.1). Try to update to latest (2.4.0)

```
$ gem update listen
```

In your `Gemfile`:

```
require 'rbconfig'

gem 'listen', '~> 2.4'
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/i
```

**Added** the gem wdm since i'm not sure if the listen gem will [require it by itself](https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/v2.4.0/README.md#on-windows) but as the readme states this is optional, otherwise it will fallback to polling which is a less efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Saying that though, running watch again after that line, and i am still getting the error. Strange, it worked a moment ago. It seesm to think it cant find wdm despite those two lines being present.

Comment: `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch`

Comment: `gem install wdm` did it for me.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. Fixed the problem very simply by setting "Windows Directory Monitor".

```
gem install wdm
```

And Include this line in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'wdm'
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post](http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2011/09/01/runningjekyllwindows.html) says:

```
# If you get the following error with the –watch option

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter.rb:207:in `require': cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)

# To fix that error, open the gemfile in your jekyll project directory and add these two lines:

require 'rbconfig'
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/i
```